# Effectively Asking manager for support on continuing education

Tags: career-development, email, manager, continuing-education

My company has a policy of funding for continuing education and I was wondering what would be the best way to convince my manager to take a course which I really like to take?

It has a lot of impact on my work but I am uncomfortable to bring this up in person or do not know the correct choice of words to use in an email to churn up a cogent argument for the same.

Edit : interested in Big Data/Data Mining space -- wish to take a course in a similar area offered by Stanford

Comment: If you don't explain in your post what is the course you want to take, we can't possibly try to help you with your problem. Could you elaborate on your idea? Also giving context on you manager, or his opinion on that policy would greatly help .

Comment: Why are you "uncomfortable" bringing it up if your company financially supports such courses (which indicates they encourage going) and that it will have a direct positive impact on your current job? Are you struggling with the wording, how and when to bring it up, etc.?

Comment: yes, partially true -- i have recently joined the team -- only a week back and haven't established enough rapport with the manager/team to speak up.

Comment: That's understandable and important to the question. As far as you know, will you be meeting regularly with your manager (1-on-1s)? Or does it seem you will have need based meetings whenever your manager or you feel you need to meet?

Comment: @cheshire there are no 1-on-1s in the company

Answer (score 5):

You have to make it clear to your manager/team what *they* will benefit from you taking this course and how it will *generate value* for them.

Pin-point some tasks or KPIs that you will be able to help on or even resolve with the knowledge you will gain from this course you're interested in. Then present this to you manager. Make a good case for it.

Continuous education of employees is a great investment if the company gets some measurable value back.

In regards to you being uncomfortable bringing it up, why?
If it's something that is very relevant for your work and would make a positive impact on your performance as an employee - don't hesitate to ask for it.

Many companies have a yearly budget for educating employees. You need to make a claim for those funds in order to further your career and them to get competent employees.

Answer (score 0):

A question is if this is a company benefit or a training budget item. If it is a benefit, I wouldn't worry about how long you have been there, and depending on the how the company benefit is structured, even if the course relates to your work. Do you worry about taking insurance right away? Read the program and see if it indicates "work related" education or not. Cases I have seen that don't specify "work related", and want the manager to "approve", are being courteous to the manager. Even if the manager said no, HR would say yes - it's an employment benefit.

If it is a training budget item, I think @diceler has good advice.